# nvd3.js rendering solution for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am considering implementing something to help display the rendered SVG graph (generated with nvd3.js) in internet explorer

The complications of this are that I'm not using d3.js which has some support for raphael.js (via D34raphael). Raphael.js basically takes svg elements and draws path around them in its wrapper functions to generate vml or svg. Some people report being able to do all the d3 logic and then casing the actual svg drawing in a raphael statement.

But NVD3.js generates svg elements in many places around the code, instead of one place.

I was looking at solutions which involve running an ajax call to my php server which will read the rendered html page, extract the rendered nvd3 svg, and create an image in its place. I'm not sure how practical that is yet, before I go down that rabbit hole.

SVGweb doesn't seem to really work, Chrome Frame isn't really an option, so I'm not sure what other people use. Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using r2d3. Its a drop in library for IE that uses the exact same syntax as D3.

https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3

Comment: I am trying it. The problem is that I'm using NVD3 which is pretty much tied to svg

Comment: You'll need to use D3 to build the SVG elements rather than including them in the HTML document.

Comment: any plans to do r2d3.v3 based on d3.v3.js ?

Comment: yeah, it should be fairly simple.  I just need to verify that the patches I made are still valid and update the git submodule to point at the latest d3 release.

Comment: @CQM how did yo achieve rendering nvd3 svg graphs on IE?

Comment: @swapneel I didn't get nvd3 to work, and I had limited luck using r2d3.js

Comment: @CQM Ok. thank you. May I ask what decision you made for displaying graph on IE. As i want to use d3 and nvd3 js

Comment: @swapneel eventually switched to http://www.flotcharts.org/ for that project since a significant near majority of the user base was using IE 8 and IE 9 and could not experience anything interesting like d3, and the data we were trying to show was not that complex of a dataset to need to create a new kind of graph