# How to make nvd3 work in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am creating a dashboard project for which i am using nvd3 but as we know svg is not supported in IE8 so it does not render graphs/charts in IE8..please suggest how i can make nvd3 work in IE8

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation and I think I may just ditch nvd3 (besides no ie8 support, I'm finding other bugs). I'm wondering, has anyone successfully used r2d3 with nvd3?

My concern is that r2d3 uses d3v3 now, which nvd3 is not presently supporting (currently d3v2... d3v3 support in the works as of writing this).

For an alternative to nvd3, I'm considering: 
[MorrisJS](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/)!
 - Works on ie8 (Raphael-based), but a newer project and less flexibility/options with the charts comparatively.

[Google Chart Engine](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/)!
 - I think this may be the way to go (for my project), I don't like that its not open source, but I'm already working extensively with the Google Maps API and this solution is very stable and easy to use from my experiences thus far. In limited testing in ie8 it works very well.

Also, here's another stackoverflow question on this topic, [question]: [nvd3.js rendering solution for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569763/nvd3-js-rendering-solution-for-internet-explorer)
 ...seems r2d3 was the accepted answer there, but no one really verified it.

Answer (score 1):

The library [r2d3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/) is "a customized build of D3 powered by RaphaelJS. The combination of D3 and Raphael enable developers to easily build data visualizations that work in IE7+ and all modern browsers." - it has its limitations (see the link for details), but it would be a good place to start

Comment: nvd3 is based directly on D3, and IE8 is IE7+