# nvd3 support for IE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, nvd3.js

I have came across the following stackoverflow questions as well. But could not find a proper answer. 
[1] [how to use nvd3.js charts with RaphaelJS for internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233080/how-to-use-nvd3-js-charts-with-raphaeljs-for-internet-explorer) 
[2] [How to make nvd3 work in Internet Explorer 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614322/how-to-make-nvd3-work-in-internet-explorer-8) 
[3] [nvd3.js rendering solution for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569763/nvd3-js-rendering-solution-for-internet-explorer)

Does nvd3 support IE 8 and below now or it is yet to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

From the NVD3 source on [Supported Browsers](https://github.com/novus/nvd3#supported-browsers)

```
NVD3 runs best on WebKit based browsers.    
 - Google Chrome: latest version (preferred)
 - Opera 15+ (preferred)
 - Safari: latest version
 - Firefox: latest version
 - Internet Explorer: 9 and 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @shabeer90. is there any workaround to get it work in IE 8 and below.