# how to use nvd3.js charts with RaphaelJS for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

Following to this [nvd3-js-rendering-solution-for-internet-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569763/nvd3-js-rendering-solution-for-internet-explorer)

any examples on how to use nvd3.js charts with RaphaelJS for internet explorer which does not support SVG

Or any links to use PhantomJS with NVD3. simmilar to [HighChartJS](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts)

I am working on to use Phantom.js to conver nvd3 graphs, but wondering if anyone here has already invented this wheel..

this is my [jsbin link for Piechart](http://jsbin.com/utobin/10/edit)

**Update**

Ok using Phantom [**rasterize.js**](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) i am able to convert my html page into png.
[Example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture)

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://ariya.github.com/svg/tiger.svg tiger.png
```

*> What i am looking for is just to pass a specific SVG Id to this js > script. i.e if I have 2 SVG charts i want to pass them individually > and create 2 PNG files and render them on Screen*